# Powertips on mouseover/enter for compatibility with DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables, pagination

I have Powertips in use on some objects in table cells inside of DataTables. The problem is, when you go to the next page, the tooltips stop working.

I found some threads saying use on mouseenter, but my table is dynamically generated and everytime I put the code into the .js, it doesn't work at all. I'm using regexp to select all the classes that start with "tt-". Here is the code I'm trying to get to work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    .on('mouseover', $('*[class*="tt-"]'), function(event) {
    });
    $('.tooltips').powerTip({
        followMouse: true,
    });
    $('.tt-1').data('powertip', `DATA`);

});
```

I've tried putting the .tooltips and .tt-1 into the .on function, but it still doesn't work. The way I have the code above stops the tooltips from working anywhere, if I remove the .on function it the tooltips will work only on the first page.

I'm not familiar with regular expression in javascript. i've tried just using

```
[class*-"tt-"]
```

without the $('* and ') but it still doesn't work.

And I can't use ^= because it is called after the tooltips class so I have to use a regexp for if it contains this string.

> Edit1

Changing

```
.on('mouseover', $('*[class*="tt-"]'), function(event) {
```

to

```
$(document).on('mouseover', $('*[class*="tt-"]'), function(event) {
```

and the final result being

```
    $(document).on('mouseover', $('*[class*="tt-"]'), function(event) {

$('.tooltips').powerTip({
    followMouse: true,
});
$('.tt-1').data('powertip', `DATA`);
    });
```

Fixed the problem, thanks to john Smith :)

> Edit2

So now it's not working anymore... I don't know what I changed.

Comment: use `$(document).on(` instead of `.on(` and check your console, that should give you an error

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if its the fix feel free to mark as answer ;)

use `$(document).on(` instead of `.on(`

Comment: It's not working anymore, I didn't really change anything. I have no idea what happened.